# javascript array - comparing elements with other elements within the same array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am comparing javascript array of elements with other elements within the same array. If elements are same means, i have to give same number for all the common elements. If the elements are different i have to give some different number for all the non identical elements in another element.

for example :

```
Array structure = [{Location, Date, Number}]


array = [{ 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'NY','2017-12-01',2},
         { 'NY','2016-10-01',3},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
         { 'LA','2017-12-01',1}]
```

In this array 'Number' is dynamic element, It should be populate on the following rules.

```
key1 = location + '-' +date;
```

Consider Key1 is the first element ( combination of location + date ). If the same key1 is present in the array, then 'Number' is common for all the same Key1.

In the above example `{'LA','2017-12-01',1 }` having the same number `1`.

`{ 'NY','2017-12-01',2}` having the number `2`. and 
`{ 'NY','2016-10-01',3},` having the number `3` because eventhough location is common but date is different.

Please find my code below.

```
var item = this.state.item;
var lines = item.order_items;
var count=1;
var key1;
var key2;

    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
        {
            key1 = lines[i].location + '-' + lines[i].date;

            for(var j=0;j<lines.length;j++)
                {
                    key2 = lines[j].location + '-' + lines[j].date;
                    if( key1 === key2 )
                        {
                            lines[i].number=count;
                            this.setState({item:item});
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            count++;
                            lines[j].number=count;
                            this.setState({item:item});
                        }
                }
        }
```

Problem is, for loop is iterating multiple times - its keep on comparing the same element multiple times. how do i can solve this issue.

Comment: do `j<lines.length` to `j<i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like the sort of problem well suited for a map. You shouldn't be looping over the array twice.

```
var item = this.state.item;
var lines = item.order_items;
var map = new Map();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    key = lines[i].location + '-' + lines[i].date;
    if (!map.has(key)) {
        map.set(key, map.size + 1);
    }
    lines[i].number = map.get(key);
    this.setState({item: item});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot., it works perfectly. one more case here - Some times `lines[i].date` wont be available, in this case i have to check for another field `lines[i].manufacture_date` how do i check for another element.   for example : `key = lines[i].location + '-' + lines[i].date ? lines[i].date : lines[i].manufacture_date;`   like this...??

Comment: To answer your question, I need you to clarify: in the case where lines[i].date doesn't exist, but lines[i].manufacturing_date matches the date for another line, are they still considered matching keys? 

For example, if we have two instances of { 'LA', '2017-12-01' }, but one has '2017-12-01' as it's date and the other has no date value but '2017-12-01' as it's manufacturing_date, should the output be [{ 'LA', '2017-12-01', 1 }, { 'LA', '2017-12-01', 1 }] or [{ 'LA', '2017-12-01', 1 }, { 'LA', '2017-12-01', 2 }] ?

Comment: I will explain in another way, `Key = lines.location + lines.date or lines.manufacture_date`. I hope you got my point. if `lines.date` is not there, then it should consider `lines.manufacture_date` instead of `lines.date`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. My question is whether it matters where the date came from. If two lines have the same location, Line 2 has no date, and Line 1's date equals Line 2's manufacturing date, what is the output? Should they have the same number or not?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Replace the 5th line with 
var key = lines[i].location + '-' + (lines[i].date ? lines[i].date : lines[i].manufacture_date);

Comment: `key = lines[i].location + '-' + (lines[i].date!=null ? lines[i].date : lines[i].manufacture_date);` Am checking for null and it is not working as expected. It giving different `Number`.

Comment: If date doesn't exist for a line, what does lines[i].date evaluate to? Is it null, undefined, an empty string, or something else?

Comment: Its empty string. If date doesnt exist

Comment: Okay. The problem is that you have put `(lines[i].date!=null...`. An empty string will never equal null. Put exactly what I originally told you to put: `var key = lines[i].location + '-' + (lines[i].date ? lines[i].date : lines[i].manufacture_date);`.

Comment: I have tried that, its also not working. so that i started testing with `!= null`. But, both of them not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160837/discussion-between-raghav-m-and-karthikeyan).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare each item to one another, your innermost for loop is starting at the wrong index. Currently you have

```
for(var j=0;j<lines.length;j++)
```

Instead, you should begin where your outer loop left off, like so (by incrementing i by one)

```
for(var j=i+1;j<lines.length;j++)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using a map you could get a more readable code and probably a more efficient program, O(n²) to O(n) assuming that accessing a map is in constant time :

```js
var n = 0;
var map = {};
var xs = [
  ['LA', '2017-12-01'],
  ['LA', '2017-12-01'],
  ['NY', '2017-12-01'],
  ['NY', '2016-10-01'],
  ['LA', '2017-12-01'],
  ['LA', '2017-12-01'],
  ['LA', '2017-12-01']
];

xs = xs.map(function (x) {
  var label = x[0] + "-" + x[1];
  if (!map[label]) map[label] = ++n;
  return x.concat([map[label]]);
});

console.log(xs);
```